# URL protocol/mimetype to autoload epub file on Nook?

Tags: epub, nook

For iphone, I use the "stanza://abcd.epub" url format to automagically startup the Stanza reader and autoload the abcd.epub book.

On the color nook, I tried a url with the epub mimetype "application/epub+zip".

The epub downloaded to the "My Downloads" folder on the color nook. It was not added to the nook's library. When I navigated within the nook to the downloads file, it was able to read and display the file.

**Question** Is there a way to download and automatically add an epub to the color nook's library or to autoload an epub and start displaying it to the user?

Answer (score 0):

Auto(down)load is probably possible by writing an app that starts on android-boot.

But I believe that you have to add your ebook to the nook store or it will not be listed within the library.